# Select all items after the first element of a type

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to select all the text within a span after the first `<hr>` tag.

I'm using this as my testing link. https://13ulbasaur.github.io/RandomTesting/

```
<span id="selectorID">
  <b>Header Text</b>
  Some more header text.
  <hr>
  Body text that I want starts here, it may also include <a href="www.google.com">links</a>, <b>bolded text</b>, and even...
  <ul>
    <li>Lists!</li>
    <li>With a bunch of items.</li>
    <li>I want these too.</li>
  </ul>
  Then after all of that, it may also include
  <hr>
  Another HR, <b>but I want this text too that comes after this.</b> As long as it's after the first hr.
</span>
```

I want all of the text, so this includes stuff in the lists, in links, etc, and stuff after the second or more `<hr>`, as long as its within the span with the selectorID ID and after the *first* `<hr>` tag.

The closest I got to was with the code below, but it refuses to give me back any of the text that is within additional tags, which makes sense since the items within the tag won't have hr as a sibling anymore.

```
//span[contains(@id,'selectorID')]/descendant-or-self::*/text()[count(preceding-sibling::hr)>0]
```

What would be the right way to do this? Ideally I don't want to actually have to use text() because it'd be nice to see when there's line breaks and stuff.

Comment: Can you provide the URL for testing it?

Comment: @Tanaike Just added it. https://13ulbasaur.github.io/RandomTesting/

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want all of the text, so this includes stuff in the lists, in links, any other tags, and stuff after the second or more <hr>, as long as its within the span with the selectorID ID and after the first <hr> tag.`, if you want to retrieve the values including the tags, I'm worried that IMPORTXML cannot be used. In this case, how about using Google Apps Script instead of the built-in function of Spreadsheet?

Comment: I think I might have used the wrong words, I don't really need the tags as in "<ul>" etc, I just meant I want the text inside those tags as well (so I want the text within the list, but I'm fine without having the "<ul>" itself). Edited the post to clarify myself.

Comment: Please do not modify the question to include additional requirements after you have already received an answer. Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't adding a new requirement I was just clarifying it better as I realised the wording could have been misread, would I have to make a new post if I wanted to make a clarification/update the wording properly on what I was looking for? [So I can get this right next time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're after but try changing your xpath expression to

```
//span[@id='selectorID']//self::node()[preceding::hr[preceding::span]]//.
```

and see if it works.

If you want to get rid of the duplicates, you can wrap the whole function with `unique()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Just have to hope I don't have duplicate items in separate areas (ie two  links that happen to have the same text)

Comment: @Twiggies Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `importdata()` and `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=regexextract( 
  join(char(10), importdata("https://13ulbasaur.github.io/RandomTesting/", "µ")), 
  "selectorID\b[\s\S]+?<hr>\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*</span>" 
)
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I didn't realise you could pull in the tags like that, so this is still super helpful, could potentially use this for formatting projects.